# proper way to normalize my distance matrices (matlab)

Tags: matlab, matrix, compare, distance

I am facing a doubt about a comparison that I want to do between two distance matrices. Lets say that I have my ground truth matrix:

```
gt = [1     0     0     0    1;
      0     1     0     0    1;
      0     0     1     0    0;
      0     0     0     1    0];
```

and then I have two other extracted matrices:

```
v1 = [0.6136    0.1012    0.1146    0.1647    0.7445;
      0.2264    0.7457   -0.0015   -0.0093    1.0026;
     -0.0107    0.1975    1.1219    0.1699    0.1926;
     -0.0019    0.0564    0.1560    0.7723    0.0565];

v2 = [0.8209    0.1390    0.1538    0.0203    0.9997;
      0.2295    0.7720   -0.0028   -0.0112    1.0329;
     -0.0167    0.2593    0.8172    0.2227    0.2501;
     -0.0000    0.0549    0.1561    1.2728    0.0569];
```

Then I want to extract the distance matrix of each column of the above matrices to the columns of the ground truth matrix `gt`. The way I am getting this distance is `dist1 = pdist2(gt', V1','euclidean');` and `dist2 = pdist2(gt', V2','euclidean');`. However, the result two distance matrices are not comparable right? Since the value range of each of the `v1` and `v2` matrices are different, therefore I need to apply a kind of normalization in order to be able to make conclusions on the result (please correct, if I am wrong).

However, I am not sure if this should be before or after I compute the distance matrices and what type of normalization to use. The negative values are playing a role of penalizing against (for that reason I am saying that I might need to apply the normalization after I compute the distance matrix, otherwise my first pick would be to normalize the `v1` and `v2` before I get their distance to the `gt`), therefore their affect should be kept and after the normalization.

Can you please give some feedback on that, how and what type of normalization to apply.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the problem exactly, but I think that `dist1` and `dist2` should be already comparable. They are both a collection of distances of points from the corresponding ground truth points, aren't they?

Comment: yes that's true `dist1` and `dist2` are the collection of distances of the columns of `v1` and `v2` from the ground truth matrix columns but as you can see my ground truth matrix has values 0 or 1 but `v1` and `v2` could have values in different ranges. If you see on column 4 of both `v1` and `v2` values vary from -0.0093 to 0.7723 and -0.0112 to 1.2728 respectively. I do not think that the result distances would be comparable. I do not think that it would be comparable even to the different columns of each matrix. Consider that its column is an individual measurement as well.